# How to make Telegram API call to `users.getUsers`

Tags: perl, telegram-bot

I am using [WWW::Telegram::BotAPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Telegram::BotAPI)

From [here](https://core.telegram.org/methods#working-with-other-users) I read I can get basic info for given `user_id`

How to accomplish this?

Next does not work:

```
$api->api_request( 'users.getUsers' ) # 404 Not Found
```

If this is not supported by module, may you please provide an example how to do this with `curl`

Comment: Check the documentation again carefully, that call needs a parameter

Comment: @m0skit0: got official answer: it is not supported yet

Answer (score 2):

Got official answer: it is not supported yet

https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=136452